# Can't find assets (404 error) in playframework 2.6.6

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.6

I've recently found that I can no longer access static assets in my 2.6.6 playframework web application. As far as I can tell, I'm doing things in a fairly conventional way:

- The assets are in `project_root/public` on the filesystem.
- My routes file contains the line
  `GET    /assets/*file                controllers.Assets.at(file: String)`
- My application.conf file contains the entry

```
play.assets {
  path = "/public"
  urlPrefix = "/assets"
}
```

So, I expect

`https://my-domain.com/assets/dirname/filename.html`

to give me the static html file at `application_root/public/dirname/filename.html` (I have static content living alongside templated content for reasons that are immaterial).

However, instead I get a 404 error. I expect I'm doing something foolish, but at a loss for what that is. In case it's relevant, I'm using sbt version 1.3.13, and again play 2.6.6. Things were working fine w/play 2.5, and I *thought* I'd migrated correctly but evidently not.

Comment: Did you solve the problem ?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I have some workarounds in place, but would still love to know what I've done wrong.